# How do you take a screenshot of the controls for taking a screenshot

Tags: screen-capture

There is an app that comes standard for taking screenshots and screen recordings. How would you take a screenshot of the control bar that pops up which allows you to select the type of screenshot and where it saves to. When I take a screenshot that bar doesn't appear in the screenshot which is desired in most scenarios, but in very rare circumstances, how would one have the screenshot actually capture that control bar as well?

Comment: I have an answer n here somewhere but on phone so can't find it… Cmd Shift 3 takes the whole screen & you can crop it from that

Comment: @Thinkr - did you try it?  4 & 5 are the same 'command' with a different interface; whilst one is active the other can't be invoked. 3 is independent - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382702/85275